# Unhandled promise rejection: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, header, promise

I have a route handler like this:

```
router.route('/callcenter/:callcenter_id/contactgroup/:contactgroup_id')
    .delete((req, res) => {
        if (typeof req.body.creator === 'undefined') {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                error: { message: 'Invalid input' }
            });
        }
        const ContactGroup = new ContactGroupModel(db, req.params.callcenter_id, logger);
        ContactGroup.read(req.params.contactgroup_id)
            .then((result) => {
                if (!result) {
                    return res.status(404).json({
                        success: false,
                        error: { message: 'Contact group not found' }
                    });
                }
                if (req.body.creator !== result.creator) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        success: false,
                        error: { message: 'Invalid input' }
                    });
                }
                return ContactGroup.delete(req.params.contactgroup_id);
            })
            .then((result) => {
                if (!result) {
                    return res.status(404).json({
                        success: false,
                        error: { message: 'Contact group not found' }
                    });
                }
                return res.json({ success: true });
            })
            .catch((error) => res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                error: { message: error }
            }));
    });
```

Both `read` and `delete` functions of `ContactGroup` are promises. And I write several tests:

```
describe('DELETE', () => {
            let id;
            beforeEach(() => ContactGroup.create(data).then((result) => id = result._id));
            it('Should return 200 if successful', (done) => {
                chai.request(app)
                    .delete('/callcenter/test/contactgroup/' + id)
                    .send({ creator: 'user__1' })
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        expect(res.status).to.equal(200);
                        expect(res.body.success).to.equal(true);
                        return done();
                    });
            });
            it('Should return 400 if input is invalid (without creator)', (done) => {
                chai.request(app)
                    .delete('/callcenter/test/contactgroup/' + id)
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        expect(res.status).to.equal(400);
                        expect(res.body.success).to.equal(false);
                        expect(res.body.error.message).to.equal('Invalid input');
                        return done();
                    });
            });
            it('Should return 400 if input is invalid (unmatched creator)', (done) => {
                chai.request(app)
                    .delete('/callcenter/test/contactgroup/' + id)
                    .send({ creator: 'user__2' })
                    .end((err, res) => {
                        expect(res.status).to.equal(400);
                        expect(res.body.success).to.equal(false);
                        expect(res.body.error.message).to.equal('Invalid input');
                        return done();
                    });
            });
            it('Should return 404 if not found', (done) => {
                ContactGroup.delete(id).then(
                    () => {
                        chai.request(app)
                            .delete('/callcenter/test/contactgroup/' + id)
                            .send({ creator: 'user__1' })
                            .end((err, res) => {
                                expect(res.status).to.equal(404);
                                expect(res.body.success).to.equal(false);
                                expect(res.body.error.message).to.equal('Contact group not found');
                                return done();
                            });
                    });
            });
            afterEach(() => ContactGroup.delete(id));
        });
```

All of them pass, but the logger records some warnings in the last two tests containg `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection`, `Can't set headers after they are sent`

I haven't got why the ultimate `catch` block in route handler gets called. I thought only when the promise function gets rejected, `catch` will occur

Comment: add `return` before `res.json()` in catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code attempts to send multiple responses for the same request and that's why you get the message about "headers have already been sent".

You have code like this:

```
ContactGroup.read(req.params.contactgroup_id).then(...).then(...).catch(...)
```

And, there are code paths where you can end up sending a response in both of those `.then()` handlers which causes that error.  In your first `.then()` handler, it appears that you think that doing:

```
return res.status(404).json(...)
```

stops the promise chain. It does not.  The promise chain continues and goes right onto the next `.then()` handler.  Since `res.status()` doens't return anything, it will go to the next `.then()` handler with `undefined` as the resolved value.  That will cause you to then do:

```
return res.status(404).json(...)
```

which causes the message about headers already being sent.

---

I'm not sure the exact flow you want, but perhaps you want something like this where you nest the second `.then()` so it doesn't execute when you've previously done a `return`:

```
router.route('/callcenter/:callcenter_id/contactgroup/:contactgroup_id').delete((req, res) => {
    if (typeof req.body.creator === 'undefined') {
        return res.status(400).json({
            success: false,
            error: {
                message: 'Invalid input'
            }
        });
    }
    const ContactGroup = new ContactGroupModel(db, req.params.callcenter_id, logger);
    ContactGroup.read(req.params.contactgroup_id).then((result) => {
        if (!result) {
            return res.status(404).json({
                success: false,
                error: {
                    message: 'Contact group not found'
                }
            });
        }
        if (req.body.creator !== result.creator) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                success: false,
                error: {
                    message: 'Invalid input'
                }
            });
        }
        return ContactGroup.delete(req.params.contactgroup_id).then((result) => {
            if (!result) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    success: false,
                    error: {
                        message: 'Contact group not found'
                    }
                });
            }
            return res.json({
                success: true
            });
        });
    }).catch((error) => res.status(400).json({
        success: false,
        error: {
            message: error
        }
    }));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's exactly the behaviour I want